# changing cell value in numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

When I run this code:

```
mreza = np.zeros((9,9))
mrezanew = np.zeros((9,9))
mreza[4, 3] = 1
mreza[3, 3] = 1
mreza[3, 4] = 1
mreza[5, 4] = 1
mreza[3, 5] = 1
print(mreza)
for x in range(1,8,1):
    for y in range(1,8,1):
        vsota = mreza[x - 1, y - 1] + mreza[x, y - 1] + mreza[x + 1, y - 1] + mreza[x - 1, y] + mreza[x + 1, y] + mreza[x - 1, y + 1] + mreza[x, y + 1] + mreza[x + 1, y + 1]
        if vsota == 3:
            mrezanew[x, y] = 1
        elif vsota == 2 and mreza[x, y] == 1:
            mrezanew[x, y] = 1
        else:
            mrezanew = 0
print(mrezanew)
```

I get next error in line 15:
TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your last condition is `mrezanew = 0`. During some iteration of the loop, `mrezanew` variable is overwritten with an `int` object. Next time when the loop runs and you try to access index `[x, y]`, it fails giving a `TypeError` as `int` object doesn't support indexing.

Answer (score 0):

mrezanew is no longer a NumPy array after your first iteration. vsota is 0 in your first iteration and because of this mrezanew becomes an integer.